# Image Encoding and compression and relation between them

Tags: image, image-processing, compression, encode

I just want to know the difference between image encoding and compression and what comes first. and also if there is a difference, should we do both or just one of them is enough. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specifically about programming and is also too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: The two words overlap in meaning. Encoding is a general name for representing something in some way, generally using a sequence of bits or bytes. Compression is a technique for reducing the number of bits. You could say that compression is a kind of encoding.